# Cannot convert value of type [com.ibm.ws.naming.util.CacheableReference] to required type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] for property

Tags: spring, hibernate, websphere-8

I have a spring (using jsf1.2 and hibernate) web application, when I try to run it in websphere8.5 I get this following exception which i am unable to debug

Below is the error stacktrace:

```
com.ibm.ws.naming.util.CacheableReference@70bf45a1[super=Reference Class Name: javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory
Type: JPAJndiLookupInfo
Content: PuId=3dsAcsFrontOfficeWeb_war#3dsAcsFrontOfficeWeb.war#3ds-acs-entityManager-pu, 3dsAcsFrontOfficeWeb_war#3dsAcsFrontOfficeWeb.war#persistence/3ds-acs-entityManager-pu, isFactory=true, isSFSB=false, , properties=[]
]

[27/01/16 10:18:27:872 WET] 0000008a FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: Incident FFDC émis sur C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\ffdc\server1_22048ced_16.01.27_10.18.27.8516602842131953426877.txt com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated 1341
[27/01/16 10:18:27:872 WET] 0000008a webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp notifyServletContextCreated SRVE0283E: Exception interceptée lors de l''initialisation du contexte : {0}
                                 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.http.UserDetailsServiceInjectionBeanPostProcessor#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cxf' defined in class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0' while setting bean property 'transactionAttributeSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor#0' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/installedApps/PC-S2M4Node01Cell/3dsAcsFrontOfficeWeb_war.ear/3dsAcsFrontOfficeWeb.war/WEB-INF/lib/3ds-acs-front-office-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/selectsystem-service-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'txInterceptor' while setting bean property 'transactionInterceptor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'txInterceptor' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/installedApps/PC-S2M4Node01Cell/3dsAcsFrontOfficeWeb_war.ear/3dsAcsFrontOfficeWeb.war/WEB-INF/lib/3ds-acs-front-office-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/selectsystem-service-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'transactionManager' while setting bean property 'transactionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/installedApps/PC-S2M4Node01Cell/3dsAcsFrontOfficeWeb_war.ear/3dsAcsFrontOfficeWeb.war/WEB-INF/lib/3ds-acs-front-office-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/selectsystem-service-context.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'com.ibm.ws.naming.util.CacheableReference' to required type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' for property 'entityManagerFactory'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.ibm.ws.naming.util.CacheableReference] to required type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] for property 'entityManagerFactory': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:722)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:410)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:282)

...
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cxf' defined in class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0' while setting bean property 'transactionAttributeSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor#0' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/installedApps/PC-S2M4Node01Cell/3dsAcsFrontOfficeWeb_war.ear/3dsAcsFrontOfficeWeb.war/WEB-INF/lib/3ds-acs-front-office-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/selectsystem-service-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'txInterceptor' while setting bean property 'transactionInterceptor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'txInterceptor' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/installedApps/PC-S2M4Node01Cell/3dsAcsFrontOfficeWeb_war.ear/3dsAcsFrontOfficeWeb.war/WEB-INF/lib/3ds-acs-front-office-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/selectsystem-service-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'transactionManager' while setting bean property 'transactionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/installedApps/PC-S2M4Node01Cell/3dsAcsFrontOfficeWeb_war.ear/3dsAcsFrontOfficeWeb.war/WEB-INF/lib/3ds-acs-front-office-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/selectsystem-service-context.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'com.ibm.ws.naming.util.CacheableReference' to required type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' for property 'entityManagerFactory'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.ibm.ws.naming.util.CacheableReference] to required type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] for property 'entityManagerFactory': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1075)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusExtensionPostProcessor.getBus(BusExtensionPostProcessor.java:62)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusExtensionPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(BusExtensionPostProcessor.java:53)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:394)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1413)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    ... 114 more
```

The added following code in my **web.xml** :

```
 <resource-ref>
   <res-ref-name>jdbc/acs_3ds_websphere_db</res-ref-name>
   <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
   <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
   <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>

<persistence-unit-ref>
   <persistence-unit-ref-name>persistence/3ds-acs-entityManager-pu</persistence-unit-ref-name>
   <persistence-unit-name>3ds-acs-entityManager-pu</persistence-unit-name>
</persistence-unit-ref>
```

in my **application-context.xml** i have the following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">


    <!-- <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="javax.persistence.Persistence" factory-method="createEntityManagerFactory">
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="3ds-acs-back-entityManager-pu" />
    </bean> -->
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="datasource" jndi-name="jdbc/acs_3ds_websphere_db" cache="true" resource-ref="true" lookup-on-startup="false"
    proxy-interface="javax.sql.DataSource"/>

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="entityManagerFactory" jndi-name="persistence/3ds-acs-entityManager-pu" />

    <bean id="transactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager"/>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true" />


</beans>
```

And for my **persistence.xml** i have :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">  


    <persistence-unit name="3ds-acs-entityManager-pu" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/acs_3ds_websphere_db</jta-data-source>    
        <properties>
             <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
             <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.CMTTransactionFactory" />
             <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.WebSphereExtendedJtaPlatform" />
             <property name="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion" value="true" />
             <property name="hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session" value="true" />
             <property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults" value="false" />
             <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
             <property name="hibernate.query.substitutions" value="true 'Y', false 'N'" />
             <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>


</persistence>
```

I added also a file WEB-INF/**ibm-web-bnd.xml** that contains :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-bnd 
    xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-web-bnd_1_2.xsd"
    version="1.2">

    <virtual-host name="default_host" />

    <resource-ref name="jdbc/acs_3ds_websphere_db" binding-name="jdbc/acs_3ds_websphere_db" />
</web-bnd>
```

I am stucked here for more than two days

Comment: Try adding `expected-type="javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory"` to the `jee:jndi-lookup` tag

Comment: @orid I add it, but get this error : 


`First component in name persistence/3ds-acs-entityManager-pu not found. [Root exception is org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0]`

Comment: CacheableReference is an internal type of the WebSphere Application Server JNDI implementation.  The JNDI lookup should resolve that type using the "JPAJndiLookupInfo", but that didn't happen for some reason.  Is there an earlier error/FFDC in the logs that would explain why the CacheableReference was not resolved?